# Creating a Fade Effect On A Div Tag Using A Separate JavaScript File

Tags: javascript, html, css, fadein, fadeout

*** *New Guy Alert* ***

I'm trying to create a simple fade effect on a  box for an assignment i'm working on. This seems like it should be easy, but i'm getting stuck. I've left the fade button at just disappearing to 0 opacity for now, but would like a smooth fade out. I understand that the opacity will need to be adjusted in small increments over a certain time span, but can't seem to get it to work correctly despite searching and searching the web and trying many things. Any advice from a patient individual out there would be greatly appreciated. I specifically would like the .js file to execute this like the rest of my buttons in this simple concept. Bonus would be clicking the button twice and allowing it to fade out and fade back in. I'd love to learn how the same button can create an effect and reverse it. I've attached two snippets, one from my .html file and one from my .js.

Thank you.

```js
  function growFunction(id){
    document.getElementById("box").style.height = "350px";
    document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = 1;
  }

  function shrinkFunction(id){
    document.getElementById("box").style.height = "50px";
    document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = 1;
  }
  
  function widenFunction(id){
    document.getElementById("box").style.width = "450px";
    document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = 1;
  }

  function tinyFunction(id){
    document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = 1;
    document.getElementById("box").style.height = "100px";
    document.getElementById("box").style.width = "100px"; 
    document.getElementById("box").style.margin = "10px";
  }

  function fadeFunction(id){
    document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = 0;
  }

  function blueFunction(id){
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = 1;
  }

  function pinkFunction(id){
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "pink";
    document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = 1;
  }

  function purpleFunction(id){
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "purple";
    document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = 1;
  }
  
  function greenFunction(id){
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "green";
    document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = 1;
  }

  function yellowFunction(id){
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = 1;
  }

  function cyanFunction(id){
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "cyan";
    document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = 1;
  }

  function resetFunction(id){
    document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = 1;
    document.getElementById("box").style.height = "250px";
    document.getElementById("box").style.width = "250px" ; 
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "orange";
    document.getElementById("box").style.margin = "25px";
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #large22px {
    font-size: 22px;
    }
    </style>
    <title>Jiggle Into JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>

    <p id="large22px">Press the buttons to change the box:</p>

    <div id="box" style="height:250px; width:250px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"></div>

    <button id="growFunction" onclick="growFunction()">Grow</button>
    <button id="shrinkFunction" onclick="shrinkFunction()">Shrink</button>
    <button id="widenFunction" onclick="widenFunction()">Widen</button>
    <button id="tinyFunction" onclick="tinyFunction()">Tiny</button>
    <button id="fadeFunction" onclick="fadeFunction()">Fade</button> 
    <button id="resetFunction" onclick="resetFunction()">Reset</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button id="blueFunction" onclick="blueFunction()">Blue</button>
    <button id="pinkFunction" onclick="pinkFunction()">Pink</button>
    <button id="purpleFunction" onclick="purpleFunction()">Purple</button>
    <button id="greenFunction" onclick="greenFunction()">Green</button>
    <button id="yellowFunction" onclick="yellowFunction()">Yellow</button>
    <button id="cyanFunction" onclick="cyanFunction()">Cyan</button>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript.js"></script>
    
</html>
```

Comment: Hey @jawnathan, for the fade effect I think you might need the CSS transition property, check it out be adding `transition:0.5s;` for example in your box style. For the toggle effect I'm thinking of a nice way to do it.

Comment: TLDR; if you do not have to use JavaScript, normally you do not, you can use CSS to achieve this with a `transition` or an `animation`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a non so elegant way to achieve something like this, it's all about what are you going for and then you build up the logic behind that. Let me know if you have any questions.

You will notice that I am calling the checkStatus function in every action, in this function I'm saving initially the status of the action in a variable (status) and then I check this variable on every click. So, if you press widen the status "widen" is saved in this variable and then if you press widen again you have this information so you can reset the values or do whatever you want.

```js
var status = "";

function growFunction(id){
    let height; 
    if(checkStatus("grow")){
      height="250px"
    }else{
      height="350px"
    }
    document.getElementById("box").style.height = height;
    document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = 1;
  }

  function shrinkFunction(id){
    let height; 
    if(checkStatus("shrink")){
      height="250px"
    }else{
      height="50px"
    }
    document.getElementById("box").style.height = height;
    document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = 1;
  }
  
  function widenFunction(id){
    let width; 
    if(checkStatus("widen")){
      width="250px"
    }else{
      width="450px"
    }
    document.getElementById("box").style.width = width;
    document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = 1;
    
  }

  function tinyFunction(id){
    let width; let height; let margin;
    if(checkStatus("tiny")){
      width="250px"
      margin="25px";
      height="250px"
    }else{
      height="100px"
      width="100px"
      margin="10px"
    }
    document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = 1;
    document.getElementById("box").style.height = height;
    document.getElementById("box").style.width = width; 
    document.getElementById("box").style.margin = margin;
  }

  function fadeFunction(id){
    let opacity; 
    if(checkStatus("fade")){
      opacity=1
    }else{
      opacity=0
    }
    document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = opacity;
  }

  function blueFunction(id){
    let color; 
    if(checkStatus("blue")){
      color="orange"
    }else{
      color="blue"
    }
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = color;
    document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = 1;
  }

  function pinkFunction(id){
    let color; 
    if(checkStatus("pink")){
      color="orange"
    }else{
      color="pink"
    }
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = color;
    document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = 1;
  }

  function purpleFunction(id){
    let color; 
    if(checkStatus("purple")){
      color="orange"
    }else{
      color="purple"
    }
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor =color;
    document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = 1;
  }
  
  function greenFunction(id){
    let color; 
    if(checkStatus("green")){
      color="orange"
    }else{
      color="green"
    }
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = color;
    document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = 1;
  }

  function yellowFunction(id){
    let color; 
    if(checkStatus("yellow")){
      color="orange"
    }else{
      color="yellow"
    }
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = color;
    document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = 1;
  }

  function cyanFunction(id){
    let color; 
    if(checkStatus("cyan")){
      color="orange"
    }else{
      color="cyan"
    }
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = color;
    document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = 1;
  }

  function resetFunction(id){
    document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = 1;
    document.getElementById("box").style.height = "250px";
    document.getElementById("box").style.width = "250px" ; 
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "orange";
    document.getElementById("box").style.margin = "25px";
  }

function checkStatus(x){
  if(status != "" && status != x){
    status = x;
    return false;
  }else{
    if(status==x){
      status = ""
      return true;
    }else{
      status = x;
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <style>
        #large22px {
    font-size: 22px;
    }
    </style>
    <title>Jiggle Into JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>

    <p id="large22px">Press the buttons to change the box:</p>

    <div id="box" style="height:250px;transition:.3s;width:250px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"></div>

    <button id="growFunction" onclick="growFunction()">Grow</button>
    <button id="shrinkFunction" onclick="shrinkFunction()">Shrink</button>
    <button id="widenFunction" onclick="widenFunction()">Widen</button>
    <button id="tinyFunction" onclick="tinyFunction()">Tiny</button>
    <button id="fadeFunction" onclick="fadeFunction()">Fade</button> 
    <button id="resetFunction" onclick="resetFunction()">Reset</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button id="blueFunction" onclick="blueFunction()">Blue</button>
    <button id="pinkFunction" onclick="pinkFunction()">Pink</button>
    <button id="purpleFunction" onclick="purpleFunction()">Purple</button>
    <button id="greenFunction" onclick="greenFunction()">Green</button>
    <button id="yellowFunction" onclick="yellowFunction()">Yellow</button>
    <button id="cyanFunction" onclick="cyanFunction()">Cyan</button>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work exactly how i had hoped, and then some.. here on stack overflow. But when using this in Visual Studio and testing in Chrome, it doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: I can only think the html file doesn't know where the javascript file is. Check for typos or the path to your js file.

Comment: Yes, i had multiple versions from prior attempts saved in different directories with different file naming conventions for the .js..That was it. Should've known. Thanks for your help, i learned exactly what was needed. I really appreciate you!

Comment: You're welcome @jawnathan, if my answer covers your issue you are welcome to accept it as a solution.